# How can we delete/remove all the customization from production environment

Tags: sandbox, production

- What is the best way to remove all the customization apex classes /
  pages from production. One way I know is using eclipse, delete the
  classes in sandbox and deploy the changes in productions. But its a
  lengthy process.
- Is there a way to reset the whole production environment? Something like factory reset?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the **Metadata API** or the **sf:deploy** task in Ant to write scripts to do this. Its not the same as a reset, but does allow you to effecetively undeploy customisations, by dynamically querying for customisations and build the **destructiveChanges.xml** file to list things to remove. At Dreamforce 2012 such a tool was presented, the code for it is [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/df12-deployment-tools).

> undeploy
>
> used to remove all metadata from the org.
>
> usage: ant undeploy

Comment: woah, this is awesome that they went for tackling this, if only i could up-vote twice!!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there currently isn't a factory reset to clear customizations, although I sure wish there was.

The best way to remove all customizations is through deployments.  If it's a known set of classes and customizations you're removing you can script the various steps using the ANT.

Comment: seems like there are no such specific guidelines or best practices declared by SF

Comment: it doesn't help that there isn't a way to get a clean org or change a lot of settings programmatically, looks like @AndrewFawcett has some pretty cool stuff to look at