# How can I reset a Sandbox to vanilla state (deleting all code and metadata customisations)?

Tags: sandbox

Is there a quick way to wipe all code and metadata customisations from a sandbox?  I'm performing several sandbox -> sandbox duplications for a complex deployment process and could do with wiping the target sandbox properly rather than relying on removing code and metadata manually (the bulk is overwritten, but there are some changes only in the target sandbox that I want to remove).

Anything like a "reset to vanilla state" process?  (NB: I don't want to reset it to be like LIVE, also I don't want to use a developer sandbox because it IS useful that the Users, Custom Settings etc are already in the Sandbox)

Cheers,
Ray

Answer (score 2):

May have found the answer here:

[How can we delete/remove all the customization from production environment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9227/how-can-we-delete-remove-all-the-customization-from-production-environment?rq=1)

which links to this extension of the Migration Tool with an "undeploy" option:

https://github.com/financialforcedev/df12-deployment-tools